# Parallelizing sparse array construction

Tags: parallelization, sparse-arrays

I have a very large sparse array, and the computation of individual matrix elements is fairly expensive. The Matrix is Hermitian and traceless, so I would like to construct only the sub-diagonal elements explicitly.

A sketch of my attempt:

```
M = SparseArray[{}, {imax, imax}];
SetSharedVariable[M];
ParallelDo[
  If[j < i, M[[i, j]] = f[i, j]],
  {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, imax}];
```

My understanding is that setting M as a shared variable this way is very expensive. Is there a good way to parallelize this process?

Note: I have seen examples where people calculate dense matrices by constructing the submatrices on separate kernels, but for my matrix the computation time of a submatrix is difficult to estimate so trying to distribute the computation time manually is difficult.

Comment: Try to use the common scheme: `SparseArray[ids -> vals]`, where `ids = {{i1,j1},{i2,j2},...}` is a list of indexes and `vals` is a list of correcpoding values.   You can calulate `vals` with `ParallelTable`. Moreover, adding elements to existing `SparseArray` takes sensible amount of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ParallelTable` and generate the `SparseArray` form the table.

```
f[i_, j_] := i + j;
imax = 50;

AbsoluteTiming[
M = SparseArray[{}, {imax, imax}];
SetSharedVariable[M];
ParallelDo[If[j < i, M[[i, j]] = f[i, j]], {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, imax}]
]
(*{8.259472, Null}*)

AbsoluteTiming[
M2 = SparseArray[Flatten[ParallelTable[{{i, j} -> f[i, j]}, {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, i - 1}]],{imax,imax}];
]
(*{0.038002,Null}*)
```

Comment: Why the j=2? It seems to work without that.

Comment: Ups, I forgot to remove this from the code. Corrected, Thanks.

Comment: Also the sparse array shape should be specified, otherwise it's not a square matrix.

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Good point, if your matrix has to be square you can specifiy the size as you did in your question.